# What is this alphanumeric number next to the type of widget?

Tags: android, android-studio

In android studio console, there is alphanumeric number next to widget. 
Example, `android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@3afd2`

What does '3afd2' in this signify? Can it be used to find the ID of widget?
PS: New to android and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

That string looks like the return value of the default implementation (in the `Object` class) of the `toString` method. According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), the `toString` method:

> returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the
>   object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned
>   hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

Basically, the number you see after the `@` is the hash code of the widget object. You can't use the hash code to find the ID of the widget (plus, [`EditorInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo) is not a widget). Hash codes are designed to be one-way only. You can read more about the contract for `hashCode` on its [documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).